# How can I setup Debug Certificate for Android ApkBuilder

Tags: android

I am trying to use 'ant' to build my android application. But it fails when it is building a debug version of my application. Here is the error:

```
BUILD FAILED
/Users/michael/Programs/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/ant/main_rules.xml:506: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/samuel/Programs/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/ant/main_rules.xml:236: com.android.sdklib.build.ApkCreationException: Debug Certificate expired on 1/5/11 8:29 PM
        at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.getDebugKey(ApkBuilder.java:277)
        at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.<init>(ApkBuilder.java:384)
        at com.android.ant.ApkBuilderTask.execute(ApkBuilderTask.java:247)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

Can you please tell me how can I get a valid debug certificate?

Thank you.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From [Android - Signing Applications](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html):

> #### Expiry of the Debug Certificate
>
> The self-signed certificate used to sign your application in debug
>   mode (the default on Eclipse/ADT and Ant builds) will have an
>   expiration date of 365 days from its creation date.
>
> When the certificate expires, you will get a build error. On Ant
>   builds, the error looks like this:
>
> ```
> debug: 
> [echo] Packaging bin/samples-debug.apk, and signing it with a debug key... 
> [exec] Debug Certificate expired on 8/4/08 3:43 PM
> ```
>
> In Eclipse/ADT, you will see a similar error in the Android
>   console.
>
> To fix this problem, simply delete the `debug.keystore`
>   file. The default storage location for AVDs is in
>   `~/.android/` on OS X and Linux, in `C:\Documents and
>   Settings\<user>\.android\` on Windows XP, and in
>   `C:\Users\<user>\.android\` on Windows Vista and Windows
>   7.
>
> The next time you build, the build tools will regenerate a new
>   keystore and debug key.

Comment: Further quote: "Note that, if your development machine is using a non-Gregorian locale, the build tools may erroneously generate an already-expired debug certificate, so that you get an error when trying to compile your application. For workaround information, see the troubleshooting topic I can't compile my app because the build tools generated an expired debug certificate."